# How to implement search through the content using regular expression in Python

Tags: python, regex, string, algorithm, search

I have a hierarchical dictionary with the "content" key:

```
{
    "content": "Name 1", 
    "name": "directory", 
    "decendent": [
         {
            "content": "Name 2", 
            "name": "subdirectory", 
            "decendent": None
        }, 
        {
            "content": "Name 3", 
            "name": "subdirectory_two", 
            "decendent": [
                {
                    "content": "Name 4", 
                    "name": "subsubdirectory", 
                    "decendent": None
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

where the "content" is a content of html file:

```
<p>It is common for content in Arabic, Hebrew, and other languages that use right-to-left scripts to include numerals or include text from  other scripts. Both of these typically flow  left-to-right within the overall right-to-left  context. </p> 
<p>This article tells you how to write HTML where text with different writing directions is mixed <em>within a paragraph or other HTML block</em> (ie. <dfn id="term_inline">inline or phrasal</dfn> content). (A companion article <a href="/International/questions/qa-html-dir"><cite>Structural markup and right-to-left text in HTML</cite></a> tells you how to use HTML markup for  elements such as <code class="kw">html</code>, and structural markup such as <code class="kw">p</code> or <code class="kw">div</code> and forms.)</p>
```

Also I have a function for searching and returning the found words:

```
import re

def look_through(d, s):
    r = []
    content = readFile(d["path"])
    content = BeautifulSoup(content)
    content = content.getText()
    pos = [m.start() for m in re.finditer(s, content)]
    if pos:
        if "phrase" not in d:
            d["phrase"] = [s]
        else:
            d["phrase"].append(s)
        for p in pos:
            r.append({"content": content, "phrase": d["phrase"], "name": d["name"]})
    for b in d["decendent"] or []:
            r += look_through(b, s)
    return r
```

I'd like to use the p (position) to extract several words before and several words after the found word in place where the content is assigned to the "content" key (including the case where the found word is in the beginning of the sentence):

```
r.append({"content": content, "phrase": d["phrase"], "name": d["name"]})
```

E.g.:

```
>>> look_through(dict, "how to write") 
[{"content": "article tells you how to write HTML where text", "phrase": "how to write", "name" : "Section_3"}]
```

How to implement it in Python using regular expression or anything else?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that your dictionary structure and how you navigate it is relevant to your problem, so I'm going to rephrase your question:

"How can I use regular expression to search for a term and get the words before and after my search term?"

The answer to this question is to use regex capture groups.

Here's an example that find the word previous and after the search term.  You may need to tweak the expression to get multiple words or punctuation as you desire:

```
import re

test_string = "How much wood could a wood chuck chuck if a wood chuck would chuck wood"
search_word = "wood"

for match in re.finditer('([^ ]*? |)%s( [^ ]*|)' % search_word, test_string):
    print "entire match: %s" % match.group(0)
    print "prev word: %s" % match.group(1)
    print "next word: %s" % match.group(2)
```

BTW, if you haven't already, check out www.regex101.com for testing out and tweaking your regex patterns.